# Pre-deployment approval email is not receiving/coming in Azure DevOps CD

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Pre-deployment approval email is not receiving/coming when we defining a group in Pre-deployment condition, whereas email is working when we mention individual email in Pre-deployment condition.

Steps I followed -

1. AzureDevOps=> Select the project => Project settings => Security
2. Create group, Group created under "DevOps Group".
3. Added member. For me I have added the managers who will approve the Production CD/ UAT CD.
4. From CD in Pre-deployment condition added the Group.
5. Triggered the CD and it's showing approval is Pending but did not received the email.

Notification -

Project settings => Notification

Delivery Settings is set to "Deliver to individual members"

Verified the "Deployment approval pending" subscription

- Deliver To => Members of Project Collection Valid Users by role
- Roles => Assigned to

If I mention Individual Email/Name then it's working.

Please let me know where do I need to change/modify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow from yesterday onward pre-deployment approval email is working for Groups (DevOps Groups) and it's reaching to respective persons. Did not change any configuration.
Not sure where was the problem. Happy to see the problem has been resolved!